# How can I fix "Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors" in a Perl module Makefile?

Tags: perl, makefile

I'm on Windows using [Strawberry Perl](http://www.strawberryperl.com/). I run `perl Makefile.pl` for the Buckwalter Encode module, that works fine. When I run `make`, it says

> Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors

What is `-e`? Which file do I go to fix the error? Apparently there's a missing curly bracket on line 1, but I don't know which file has that missing curly bracket so I don't know where to look.

Comment: Let's see all the errors the one you report will be at the end and tells us nothing - the first error is what matters

Comment: All the errors: 
syntax error at -e line 1, next char )
Missing right curly or square bracket at -e line 1, at end of the line
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
make: *** [pm_to_blib] Error 255

BUT that doesn't matter any more because it turned out that since I'm using Strawberry Perl, I should use dmake, not make. So I used it. I ran dmake, it worked, then dmake test (got RESULT=PASS). But  on the last command "dmake install", I got: "Error: detected circular macro" PREFIX.

So there's still an error.

Comment: edit the answer to add more information. :)

Answer (score 2):

We use perl's -e option to specify on the command line code to be executed. From [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

> - **`-e commandline`**
>     may be used to enter one line of program. If **`-e`** is given, Perl will not look for a filename in the argument list. Multiple **`-e`** commands may be given to build up a multi-line script. Make sure to use semicolons where you would in a normal program.

For example:

```
$ perl -e 'print "Hello, world!\n"'
Hello, world!
```

An error similar to the one you're seeing is

```
$ perl -e 'while (1) { print "foo!"'
Missing right curly or square bracket at -e line 1, at end of line
syntax error at -e line 1, at EOF
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, from make to dmake to cpan.. I just switched to using the CPAN client, and did 
"test Encode::Buckwalter" and then
"install Encode::Buckwalter" and it worked fine!
Don't know why the errors happened then... perhaps some platform issues..

Comment: On Windows, Perl uses either `nmake` or `dmake`.  You might have a `make.exe`, but I doubt it's the one Perl expects.  I believe you have to use the make that your Perl was compiled for.  Try `perl -e "use Config; print $Config{make}"` to see which kind of make it wants.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `perl Makefile.PL`, you create a file called `Makfefile`. Inside that file are various targets, such as `test` and `install`, that do the real work. Some of those are implemented as Perl one-liners using `-e`.

You've already solved your problem by using the right variant of make, though.